# Changing GA property after changing domain?

Tags: google-analytics, domains, migration

One of our clients migrated to the new domain.
I want to know what should I do on the existing Google Analytics property?

Answer (score 3):

That does depend on how it's set up, as there may be a number of different things. A good checklist to follow is:

1. Update the settings on the property with the new domain. Exactly what you need to change does depend on if they're using UA or GA4. In UA it's under the property settings. In GA4 you need to update the data feed settings.

Further to just the property settings, make sure you create a new Search Console property for the new domain and link Analytics to it.

2. Check the tracking code. Make sure they update to the latest version for their new domain rather than copy across the old one, that should prevent any problems there.
3. Make sure any filters are updated to reflect the new domain.
4. Make sure any referral exclusions are updated to reflect the new domain.
5. Make sure any goals are updated to reflect the new domain. This means destination goals (especially if they change the page structure) or any triggers on GTM events work with the new domain name and/or page structure.
6. If they're using UA, make an annotation on the Analytics account to mark when the change happened. Open the little box beneath the graph on an Acquisition report, click "Make new annotation" and add a note that the domain was changed on that date. That way you can always point to it when your client asks why the sudden change on that date a year from now (and if your clients are anything like mine, they will ask).